# How do we calculate the gradient from numerical data

Tags: numerical-methods, vector-analysis

I have a 3D irregular mesh. Each coordinate point holds a specific data, say , for example, temperature.

For a specific point, how do I calculate the temperature gradient ?

Comment: You have a reasonable answer below (not from me btw) - you might consider accepting.

Answer (score 7):

Ideally in this scenario, you would not have the data just at the mesh points, but would rather be doing some kind of a finite element type construction, which would give you the temperature as a *function* on each *mesh element*. Then the gradient would be given as part of the profile (i.e. you could analytically differentiate at every point except perhaps points on the boundary of a mesh element).

The next best thing would be data points on a regular mesh. Then you could approximate the partial derivatives directly, and assemble them into the gradient vector.

Since you don't even have that, you can do the following. At a mesh point $x$, find three nearby mesh points $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Then $\frac{f(x)-f(x_i)}{\| x-x_i \|}$ should be approximately the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in the direction $x-x_i$. That directional derivative is exactly $\nabla f(x) \cdot \frac{x-x_i}{\| x-x_i \|}$.

Now assume for numerical purposes that

$$f(x)-f(x_i)=\nabla f(x) \cdot (x-x_i).$$

This is a system of three linear scalar equations in three scalar unknowns (namely the components of $\nabla f(x)$). Provided the $x-x_i$ are linearly independent, it has a unique solution, so you can solve it in principle. Depending on how irregular your mesh is, you could have issues with numerical instability.

Comment: I cant use a finite element type method using the shape functions as my values are derived quantities, i have 1 value per element (esp at the integration point).




I have found one more method using the weighted difference formula involving surrounding points

Comment: @prithivirajanVeerappan 1. I know that you can't always use a finite element type method. It is just preferable in these kinds of situations. 2. That weighted difference formula can be derived using the procedure I just suggested.